# JavaScript redirect using URL parameters that contains "@"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect to a new page on button click using JS function.

The URL should contain email address parameter.

```
<form>
<input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" required/>
<input type="submit" value="SEND US THE LIST" onclick="redirect();"/>

<script>
function redirect(){
    var email = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    window.location.replace("https://rinateithan.com/thank-you?sender="+email);

}
</script>
```

I have tested my code, once I use normal string with "@" and "." symbols the code works fine.
But once I use email address in the URL parameters the redirect fails.

```
Console.log("https://rinateithan.com/thank-you?sender="+email); // Returns https://rinateithan.com/thank-you?sender=test@gmail.com for example
```

How can I transfer email address through URL parameters using JavaScript redirection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "URL encode", there's for example the `encodeURIComponent` function in Javascript that you can use to encode special chars like '@'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is not allowed in the url

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
const email = 'test@gmail.com'
console.log("https://rinateithan.com/thank-you?sender="+encodeURIComponent(email));
```

Comment: Yes but that still doesn't work for some reason.

I've applied it on my code.

Comment: if I try the following string: "test@" it works, if I try "test@gmail" it doesn't work, why is that?